# Jquery Rounded Corners not working whilst making an ajax call.. Any ideas

Tags: jquery, ajax, rounded-corners

So i've been doing quite a simple ajax call to grab my photo albums  with some pagination. My rounded corners worked before i added the ajax calls. The selectors are correct as well. I'm doing the 'cornering' on the callback for my .load and yet i can't get it to work :s Any ideas:

```
//Display Loading Image
function Display_Load()
{
    $("#loading").fadeIn(900,0);
    $("#loading").html("<img src='/images/loading.gif' />");
}
//Hide Loading Image
function Hide_Load()
{
    $("#loading").fadeOut('slow');      
};

function display_corners()
 {
            $('.album_shell li .album_photo_shell').corner("round 3px").parent().css('padding', '6px').corner("round 13px");
            $('.album_photo').corner("round 5px").parent().css('padding', '4px').corner("round 6px");
};
```

//Default Starting Page Results

```
$("#pagination_nav li:first").css({'color' : '#FF0084'}).css({'border' : 'none'});

Display_Load();
var album_id = $(document).getUrlParam("album_id"); 
$("#content").load("pagination_data.php?page=1&album_id=" + album_id, Hide_Load(),display_corners());

//Pagination Click
$("#pagination_nav li").click(function(){

    Display_Load();

    //CSS Styles
    $("#pagination_nav li")
    .css({'border' : 'solid #dddddd 1px'})
    .css({'color' : '#0063DC'});

    $(this)
    .css({'color' : '#FF0084'})
    .css({'border' : 'none'});

    //Loading Data
    var pageNum = this.id;

    $("#content").load("pagination_data.php?page=" + pageNum + "&album_id=" + album_id, Hide_Load(),display_corners());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the actual functions vs. just passing references. Additionally, you are passing two separate functions vs. just one that the `load` method accepts. You should change it to something like this:

```
$("#content").load("pagination_data.php?page=1&album_id=" + album_id, function(){
    Hide_Load();
    display_corners();
});
```

I would abstract it like this:

```
function get_album( album_id, page_number ){
   if(!page_number) page_number = 1;
   Display_Load();
   $("#content").load("pagination_data.php?page=1&album_id=" + album_id, function(){
      Hide_Load();
      display_corners();
   });
};
```

Comment: Well dude, i've learnt something today ;) Cheers for your help worked like a charm.

Comment: Happy to help! Welcome to StackOverflow. Hope to see you around!

Comment: Love looking back at 6 years ago :D

Comment: Look back at 11 years ago!!